# Python Adaptor pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, adapter

Say I have the following class

```
class MultiplePeopleInBook(object):
    def __init__(self, names, ages, book_title):
        self._names = names
        self._ages = ages
        self._book_title = book_title

    @property
    def names(self):
        return self._names

    @property
    def ages(self):
        return ages

    @property
    def book_title(self):
        return book_title
```

Now I need to have another class, say this one represents a book with exactly 1 person in it.

```
class SinglePersonInBook(object):
    def __init__(self, multiple_person_object):
        self._person = multiple_person_object

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._person.names[0]

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._person.ages[0]
```

So, I would create a MultiplePeopleInBook object like this:

```
mpib = MultiplePeopleInBook(['Bob', 'Foo'], [12,24],'foo book')
```

and a SinglePersonInBook like the following:

```
spib = SinglePersonInBook(MultiplePeopleInBook(['Bar'], [122], 'bar book')
```

Questions:
Am I setting this up correctly?

How do I get the book_title for spib? Do I need to have a method for that in the SinglePersonInBook adapter? If so, then what is the point of making it an adapter?

Can I write my **init** method for SPIB like this:

```
def __init__(self, name, age, book_title):
    self._person = MultiplePeopleInBook([name],[age],boo_title)
```

this way, I could create a SPIB object like this:

```
spib = SinglePersonInBook('Bar', 122, 'bar book')
```

This looks much cleaner to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the book_title for spib? Do I need to have a method for that in the SinglePersonInBook adapter? If so, then what is the point of making it an adapter?

Yes, you do. Making an adapter is pointless in your example. Better solution is to make an abstraction for people in book with two implementations (single and multi). The basic question is - what for do you need it ?

> Can I write my init method for SPIB like this:
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, name, age, book_title):
>     self._person = MultiplePeopleInBook([name],[age],boo_title)
> ```
>
> this way, I could create a SPIB object like this:
>
> ```
> spib = SinglePersonInBook('Bar', 122, 'bar book')
> ```
>
> This looks much cleaner to me

You can, but simple abstraction is better in this case.